# Request Wait Time is steady in IIS (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis, performancecounter, solarwinds-orion

I'm monitoring my application health in SolarWinds, the strange thing I'm noticing that the **Request Wait Time Counter is steady**. It is not changing for quite a few hours even though there are no requests in the queue and also the Requests/Sec is not that much. Is there any specific reason for the same? What can be the possible reason?

Answer (score 0):

Request Wait Time

The number of milliseconds that the most recent request waited in the queue for processing.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxk122b4.aspx

In other words: This value should remain the same until IIS processes another request.

Credit: https://serverfault.com/a/579180